# How to cause a powershell script to exit at a specified time (utc)

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that runs most of day. It's started every morning via windows task scheduler, and it needs to close itself down every night at 23:30:00 UTC.

My efforts so far have been based on this...

```
    if ( (get-date).ToUniversalTime() -ge (get-date "23:30:00") ) # Shutdown at 23:30 UTC
    {
      fnCleanShutdown # Close Connections and shutdown
    }
```

When I tested this in the morning (changing "23:30:00" to an appropriate value a minute or two before I ran the test) then the script exited at the required time as desired. When I ran the script 'live' (with the exit time as shown) then the script continues running and doesn't exit. I have tried testing after 12 noon, and it seems that the hard-coded time will only work using 12hr notation.

How do I make the script exit at 23:30:00 UTC?

Thanks

Comment: `Get-Date` will output a `DateTime` in local time (`Kind` member is `Unspecified`). You can use a `DateTimeOffset` object to work in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

```
[datetime]$exitTime = $(get-date -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy 23:30:00")
if ( (get-date).ToUniversalTime() -ge $exitTime ) # Shutdown at 23:30 UTC
{
  fnCleanShutdown # Close Connections and shutdown
}
```